# Getting '405 Not Allowed' for PUT/POST Methods in postman in mule 4

Tags: mule4

I have created a mule application with client_id and client_secret, TLS keystore and deployed on cloudhub. I am able to run application locally but cannot run with cloudhub url.

URL: https://system.us-e2.cloudhub.io/api/refund with PUT method with json body.

It is throwing '405 Not Allowed'
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are not pointing to the right application. The error is coming from CloudHub load balancer, indicating that it didn't reach your application. Check that the URL used is the right one for the application. Also that the application is listening in the right port. For CloudHub an HTTPS listening application has to listen in port 8082.

You can try to troubleshoot by contacting directly the application's worker. For example: https://mule-worker-system.us-e2.cloudhub.io/api/refund:8082/...

Your application should have an HTTP Listener configuration like:

```
<http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8082" protocol="HTTPS">
  <tls:context>
    <tls:trust-store path="keystore.jks" password="123456"/>
  </tls:context>
</http:listener-connection>
```

Note that in this configuration the port used is "8082".

Comment: URL that I am using is correct. But where to check  application is listening to 8082 port?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I have set HTTP Listener connection to 8082, still 405 Not Allowed is seen in postman